# "Undefined" Global Variable - Very odd

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, global

Folks,

I specified a global variable in 'global.js' as follows:

```
var GAME = {
    board: { 
        /* some custom properties here */ 
    },
    ...
}
```

In my HTML file, I am loading my script files in the following order:

```
<script src="/script/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/script/global.js"></script>
<script src="/script/setup.js"></script>
<script src="/script/main.js"></script>
```

In the 'main.js', which is loaded at the very end, is a simple jQuery statement as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    MyFunction();
});
```

And 'MyFunction' is defined in 'setup.js' file, in which I declared a variable as follows:

```
var board = GAME.board;
```

I'd think this should be a straightforward exercise of loading a series of script files in the specified order, waiting until all the scripts are loaded, then invoking 'MyFunction' which makes a reference to the global variable 'GAME'. But, when I load it in Firefox I get the `TypeError: GAME is undefined` error. Adding further to my confusion, the IDE's intelli-sense picks up all of GAME's member objects (including 'board') at its reference point so there's no doubt that the global variable is properly recognized at least within the IDE context.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Check your js error console and make sure there aren't any errors that are happening while `global.js` is getting executed.

Comment: @go-oleg I see no error/exception coming from `global.js` in the browser console.

Comment: Please supply a complete global.js (reduced as much as possible, but not so much that it removes the problem entirely)

Answer (score -1):

Try reorder js files, i used to define global file before all other file.
I think correct order must be

```
<script src="/script/global.js"></script>
<script src="/script/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/script/setup.js"></script>
<script src="/script/main.js"></script>
```

In lastest project i defined global variable inside a `<script>` tag instead of a file. And it work fine.

Comment: I don't think this would fix anything.  The probability that `jquery.js` depends on `global.js` is pretty much 0.

Comment: So try to defined them in a script tag